# Raphaël.js and converting of SVG is not correct scale

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have a [.svg file](http://imgh.us/skane_simple_(copy).svg) that I want to convert to Raphaël.js format. As you can see, the picture is good, everything in it is shown correctly.

I have tried converting it to the raphael format with this homepage: http://www.readysetraphael.com/ but it doesn't understand the viewports somehow. Huge parts of the map is removed.

[image]

I guess it has something to do with the fields:

```
viewBox="425 -225 800 800"
enable-background="new 425 -225 800 800"
```

in the svg-file.

I wan't to keep info about the lakes and the municipality shown in the map. I've seen other sites have some kind of conversion, but readysetreaphael has the nicest output. It, however, doesn't look good.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aL6ch7dL/

Comment: So have you tried setting the viewBox to match, in Raphael ?

Comment: Yes,  1200 and 1200.  Should the offset also be present?  If so,  how?

Comment: I would imagine with setViewBox http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setViewBox

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: rsr.setViewBox(425,-225,800,800); did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsr.setViewBox(425,-225,1200,1200)

Works good.

The documentation is really good for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Use Inkscape to edit the svg file.

Crop the map, move the top left corner to (0,0) and scale it to the size you want it to be.

Name the paths so you know what it is after when converting to Raphael.

Save it as "Optimized Svg".

Open it in your text editor and copy path tag text inside the d="..." attribute exactly as it is as Raphael path.

It's the only way you can control what you keep.